# How to navigate to another page after calling click?

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am trying to get all the main links, then click on them and navigation to the page:

```
    WebClient client = new WebClient();

    HtmlPage page = client.getPage(url);

    // Get all links with a href of www.example.com/pages/1_

    List<HtmlAnchor> links = (List<HtmlAnchor>) page.getByXPath("//a[href='www.example.com/pages/1_*'");

    links[0].click();
```

After calling click, does it return a HtmlPage? (The [NetBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) documentation is not telling me.)

Does the [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) expression look OK?

Comment: page.getByXPath should return a List so I don't think there is any need to cast it to 'List'.

Then, by links[0], I assume you mean links.get(0).

Comment: mrblah: Note the changes Peter Mortensen made -- casting to List<HtmlAnchor> as opposed to just casting to List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how documentation works in NetBeans but the documentation is all available online, and [if you go to it](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlElement.html#click%28%29), you'll see that the return type is `<P extends Page>` which will probably be HtmlPage most of the time, but could also be XmlPage or something like that.

> Simulates clicking on this element,
>   returning the page in the window that
>   has the focus after the element has
>   been clicked. Note that the returned
>   page may or may not be the same as the
>   original page, depending on the type
>   of element being clicked, the presence
>   of JavaScript action listeners, etc.